# What statistical test to use for discrete predictor and response variables?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation

I'm doing a statistical analysis of a model for college. It's modelling a bear catching fish and I'm asking will the amount of time taken to digest the fish have an effect on the amount of fish caught? (stupid question I know!)
So the predictor variable is the amount of fish the bear can eat before it needs to digest and the response variable is the amount of fish it catches.
The predictors varies between 1 and 30 in integers and the response is also in integers.
I repeated each level of the predictor 5 times creating a sample size of 150 altogether.
I was thinking of just using a simple correlation test such as cor.test in R, but I've read online that this is for continuous data. Does that matter or would this test still be appropriate?
Thanks a million,

Eamon

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Poisson regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/) or [Negative Binomial Regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/negative-binomial-regression/). Negative Binomial Regression is appropriate when the response variable exhibits overdispersion. On the other hand, if the variability of the outcome variable is constant as the predictor varies, Poisson Regression will suffice. (In a Poisson distribution of parameter $\lambda$, both the mean and the variance equal $\lambda$)
To answer your question you need to test the slope of the model. If the slope is not significantly different from zero, then there is no evidence that the amount of time taken to digest the fish affects the amount of fish caught.
There might be a non linear relationship between the response and the predictor: try to include in the model a quadratic transformation of the predictor along with its main effect.

Comment: Thanks that's great advice, I didn't know about either of those tests. So the response doesn't vary constantly as the predictor changes, does that mean I should definitely use the negative binomial regression? How do I know if the response exhibits overdispersion? And could you expand a little on what you mean by a quadratic transformation of the predictor? I think it's true that there's a non-linear relationship because the data shows a strong relationship as the predictor varies from 1-15 but a very weak relationship as it varies from 16-30.

Comment: Also, is doing a pearson's correlation test in R using cor.test absolutely wrong?

Comment: You need to understand the assumptions of pearson's correlation test. List all of them and check if they are all met by the data. If so, you can apply the test without worry. Sorry for the short answer but I don't know Pearson's correlation test very well. I can't help you any further. I just told you how I would solve the problem: there might be more than one method to solve the problem. If it is for an assignment, it is very likely that you'll need a statistical method that you already heard during lessons